# Regarding disposal of Scoped Batch animations in UWP

Tags: c#, windows, xaml, memory-management, uwp

I am creating animations in C# using the Windows 10 Composition APIs. More specifically, I am batching together animations using the method shown [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.composition.compositionscopedbatch) and it's accomplishing what I need.

My question is, the technique offers an event End() which is triggered whenever a batch is completed. I'm using this to chain up multiple animations on different UI elements. Should I also use this method to do some clean-up of the previous set of animations, since I don't need them anymore? They're made using local variables anyway.

Here is my code detailing what I mean:

```
  private void GreetingTB_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var _compositor = new Compositor();

         _compositor = ElementCompositionPreview.GetElementVisual(GreetingTB).Compositor;
        var _visual = ElementCompositionPreview.GetElementVisual(GreetingTB);

        var _batch = _compositor.CreateScopedBatch(CompositionBatchTypes.Animation);

        var animation = _compositor.CreateScalarKeyFrameAnimation();
        animation.Duration = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 2, 0);
        animation.InsertKeyFrame(0.0f, 0.0f);
        animation.InsertKeyFrame(1.0f, 1.0f);

        _batch.Completed += Batch_Completed;
        GreetingTB.Text = "Hello!";
        _visual.StartAnimation("Opacity", animation);
        _batch.End();
    }

    private void Batch_Completed(object sender, CompositionBatchCompletedEventArgs args)
    {
        args.Dispose();

     // Create new animation here
    }
```

I have called the args.Dispose() method, just in case. But I want to know if there's a better way. Is there a need to use the "sender" object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it's a best practice to always dispose objects that implements `IDisposable` as soon as you are done using them, you should dispose `_batch` in your event handler. The easiest way to do this is to wrap it in a `using` statement:

```
using (var _batch = _compositor.CreateScopedBatch(CompositionBatchTypes.Animation))
{
    ...
    _batch.End();
}
```

Once the batch has been closed it cannot be used any longer so make sure that you don't try to do anything with the `sender` argument in the `Completed` event handler.